# Create hive external table with complex data type and load from CSV or TSV having few columns with serialized JSON object

Tags: json, csv, hive, create-table, complex-data-types

I have CSV (or TSV) with a column ('nw_day' in example below) having serialized array object and another column ('res_m' in example below) having serialized JSON object. It also has columns with STRING, TIMESTAMP, and FLOAT data type.

For the TSV that looks somewhat like (showing first row)

```
+----------+---------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  com_id  |    w_start_time     |  cap  |                   nw_day                      |                                res_m                                   | 
+----------+---------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  dtf_id  | 2019-04-24 06:00:03 | 444.3 | {'Fri','Mon','Sat','Sun','Thurs','Tue','Wed'} | {"some_str":"str_one","some_n":1,"some_t":2019-04-24 06:00:03.700+0000}|
+----------+---------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have tried the following statement, but it is not giving me perfect results.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name(
  com_id STRING,
  w_start_time TIMESTAMP,
  cap FLOAT,
  nw_day array <STRING>, 
  res_m STRUCT <
    some_str: STRING,
    some_n: BIGINT,
    some_t: TIMESTAMP
  >)
  COMMENT 's_e_s'
  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
  COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ','
  STORED AS TEXTFILE
  LOCATION '/location/to/folder/containing/csv'
  TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

So, I'm thinking I deserialize those objects into hive complex datatypes with ARRAYS and STRUCT. But that is not exactly what I get when I run

```
select * from table_name limit 1;
```

which gives me

```
+----------+---------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  com_id  |    w_start_time     |  cap  |                                   nw_day                             |                                                          res_m                                                             | 
+----------+---------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  dtf_id  | 2019-04-24 06:00:03 | 444.3 | ["{'Fri'"," 'Mon'"," 'Sat'"," 'Sun'"," 'Thurs'"," 'Tue'"," 'Wed'}"]  | {"some_str":"{\"some_str\":\"str_one\",\"some_n\":1,\"some_t\":2019-04-24 06:00:03.700+0000}\","some_n":null,"some_t":null}|
+----------+---------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So, it considering the whole object as a string and split the string by delimiter.

I need some help understanding how to load data from CSV/TSV to complex data types in Hive.

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46935265/hive-how-to-explode-a-json-column-embedded-in-a-csv-file) but the requirement is little different and there is no complex datatype involved in there.

Any help would be much appreciated. If this cannot be done and a preprocessing step has to be included prior to loading, some example of input data to complex datatype loads in hive would help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: please post your csv, It seems a issue with delimiter only.

Comment: Thanks, but the csv is very similar to the example. I have renamed word by word, but the format is exactly the same. 

The first row in tsv is looking like (for this example)

dtf_id    2019-04-24 06:00:03   444.3  {'Fri','Mon','Sat','Sun','Thurs','Tue','Wed'} 
 {"some_str":"str_one","some_n":1,"some_t":2019-04-24 06:00:03.700+0000}

Comment: I am not able to check it now. can you just go through below links. seems it can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812025/hive-nested-array-in-map-data-type & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45647111/apache-hive-complex-datatype-mapstring-struct-not-working .. Thanks

Comment: @lulu, I have same king of requirement, Can you please share how did you resolve this issue?